# Linux: does a system call have its own signal handler? Can I override it?

Tags: linux, signals, posix, system-calls, signal-handling

The document on system call [read()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) says `read()` immediately returns if it is interrupted by a signal. The returned value reflects how many bytes it successfully read so far. It seems to imply some system calls have their own signal handlers.

If `read()` is reading from a pipe (set up by `pipe()`), but there is no byte available in the pipe, so `read()` is blocking the thread. Now, if I send a `SIGINT` from terminal (by Ctrl+C), the program will terminate.

Suppose at the program's start I installed a signal handler for `SIGINT` that prints a message `"SIGINT is received"`. When `read()` is blocking and I use Ctrl+C, will the program  terminate with that message printed, or will the program still terminate silently because `SIGINT` is already handled by `read()`'s signal handler?

(My experiment suggest it's the latter case.. not sure)

Comment: System calls don't have their own signal handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to imply some system calls have their own signal handlers.

No, Absolutely not. According to [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) man page when read is interrupted by signal it returns EINTR. To realize this behaviour you have to handle the signal i.e. install handler for it. if you send signal without handling it then program will terminate.

Now suppose you have handled SIGINT signal and sent it when program is blocked on [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) then two behaviors can be observed depending on how you install signal handler.

1. if signal is handled using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)  and **SA_RESTART** is used then according to [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page, handler will execute and read will be automatically restarted after the signal handler returns.
2. If **SA_RESTART** flag is not used then call fails with the error EINTR.

In both the cases program will not terminate, as SIGINT is handled.

> Suppose at the program's start I installed a signal handler for SIGINT that prints a message "SIGINT is received". When read() is blocking and I use Ctrl+C, will the program terminate with that message printed, or will the program still terminate silently because SIGINT is already handled by read()'s signal handler?

In both the case program will not terminate. Handler message "SIGINT is received" will printed and program will continue its execution.